# How to add more Content in specific Templates (Android Automotive)?

Tags: limit, listitem, android-automotive

So i am currently playing around with Android Automotive and was trying out different Templates.
Now i found out that the content limit of different Templates is restricted by the Host-Vehicle.
For Example the ListTemplate only allows 6 contents(Rows).

I'm using the generic system image provided by Android Studio.
Is it possible to change the content limit on the emulator?

By using the ConstraintManager it's possible to get the content limit of different templates but not change it.

```
constraintManager.getContentLimit(ConstraintManager.CONTENT_LIMIT_TYPE_LIST))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the limit can vary by regions and vehicles, there's no way for you as a developer to change the limit. This is because the limit is there to adhere to safety guidelines and regulations – making it modifiable would defeat that purpose. Do note that the [minimum values](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:car/app/app/src/main/java/androidx/car/app/constraints/ConstraintManager.java;l=63-106?q=%22no%20smaller%20than%22&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport:car%2Fapp%2F) for these limits can be found [here](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:car/app/app/src/main/res/values/integers.xml;l=1?q=grid%20limit%20car%20app%20xml&sq=).